# Positioning dynamic image and text in a custom cell xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, dynamic, custom-cell

I am writing an app where people are displayed in a table view.

This is the code in **PictureListMainTable.m**

```
// Get the core data object we need to use to populate this table cell
Pictures *currentCell = [pictureListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImageView *myImg = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];




//  Fill in the cell contents
cell.textLabel.text = [currentCell title];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [currentCell desc];
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentCell smallPicture]];



cell.telephoneNumber = [currentCell desc];

cell.delegate = self;

return cell;
```

I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image: Dynamic name and Image]

Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Im not sure on how to achieve this positioning, at the moment the image and title are placed side by side

Comment: You just position them in IB the way you want. Both the image view and the label should have a centerX constraint. The image view would need a constraint to the top of the cell and probably height and width constraints. The label should have a constraint to the bottom of the cell.

Comment: Could you give me an example because I'm new to this?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't something easy to write up since you do it all in IB. If you don't know how to work with auto layout, you should watch the 3 videos from the 2012 WWDC on this subject.

Comment: whats ib? ok ill take a look

Comment: and also do you know how to just align the image to the center of the cell?

Comment: You just drag it to the center -- when you get it there you will see a vertical line telling you that you're are at centerX.

Comment: I do that but the image still Is positioned to the left

Comment: You must have missed it then. Look at the Size Inspector for the image view. Do you see a constraint  that says "Align Center X to: superview"?

Comment: No i dont, but will this make all the dynamic images align to the center?

Comment: @IdsSurrrrr may this will give you some idea about the poisoning of image in custom cell. have a look on this https://github.com/romaonthego/RETableViewManager